# The automorphism group of Fano plane is made up of 6 conjugacy classes

Tags: combinatorics

Could someone please explain me why the automorphism group of Fano plane is made up of 6 conjugacy classes?
i proved that its has 168 objects, but cant find nice way to show the specific classes.
i know it has the identity one, 21 with 2 2-cycle,  42 with one 4-cycle and one 2-cycle, 56 with two 3-cycles and 48 with 7-cycle (with two distinct conjugacy classes of 24).

Is there a combinatorical way to show this?